# Infinite loop when triggering effect with Ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2, ngrx-effects, state-management

I am a little novice with the use of **Rxjs** and **Ngrx** and I have a problem that whenever an authentication error occurs the `alert()` is displayed with the error message returned from Firebase.

The problem is that when the error occurs I just want to display a message with the error ... it goes into an infinite loop and the memory usage increases and I'm forced to close the application.

When I enter the email and password correctly, the application behaves the right way ... The problem occurs whenever a Firebase error is returned.

The infinite loop does not occur if I do not create an `Effect()` for `AUTH_ERROR` ... and I get the error in the application state viewed **Redux DevTools**.

```
@Effect()
    loginWithEmailPassword: Observable<Action> = this._actions.pipe(
        ofType(authActions.LOGIN_EMAIL_PASSWORD),
        map((action: authActions.LoginEmailPassword) => action.payload),
        switchMap(data => from(this._angularFireAuth.auth
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(data.email, data.password)).pipe(
                switchMap(response => forkJoin([
                    from(response.user.getIdTokenResult(true)),
                    of(response.user)
                ])),
                map(([token, user]) => {

                    if (user) {
                        this._router.navigate(['']);

                        return new authActions.Authenticated({
                            admin: token.claims.admin,
                            profissional: token.claims.profissional,
                            assinante: token.claims.assinante,
                            firestoreCollection: token.claims.firestoreCollection,
                            user: user
                        });
                    }
                }),
                catchError((error) => of(new authActions.AuthError({ error: error })))
            ))
    )

    @Effect()
    authError$: Observable<Action> = this._actions.pipe(
        ofType(authActions.AUTH_ERROR),
        tap(action => alert(action.payload.error.message))
    )
```

Comment: Did you handle Authenticated action effect ? The error may come from there.

Comment: When authentication occurs, the state changes with the authenticated user's data. When authentication error occurs I would just like to display the error message, but it gets in an infinite loop with the tap() operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, I passed as dispatch parameter as false.

```
 @Effect({ dispatch: false })
    authError$: Observable<Action> = this._actions.pipe(
        ofType(authActions.AUTH_ERROR),
        tap(action => alert(action.payload.error.message))
    )
```